# Are EPS images supported with Apache-FOP 2.3 version?

Tags: apache-fop

I'm seeing this error when trying to add .EPS file to my PDF document,

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue in

```
Apache-FOP setup : SEVERE: Image not available. URI: ../graphics/icon-note.eps (application/postscript). 

Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: Cannot load image (no suitable loader/converter combination available) for ../graphics/icon-note.eps (application/postscript) (No context info available) 

org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: Cannot load image (no suitable loader/converter combination available) for ../graphics/icon-note.eps (application/postscript)
```

Are .EPS files supported by Apache-FOP ??

Answer (score 1):

See the Apache FOP support web site.
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/graphics.html

I would note that I do not believe EPS was ever supported in PDF output. As is the case with many formatters, EPS are available to use in Postscript output only. PDF as an image is normally available in PDF output. Some formatters allow EPS in PDF as long as the EPS has the associated TIFF embedded inside (in which the TIFF image is used so that is no different that having a TIFF image).

Your solution is to use a tool to convert you EPS images into something else that is supported in PDF output or output Postscript and use a product to convert the Postscript to PDF.